# Get all elements of a select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two select-multi lists and I want to get all the elements of the right list regarding if they are selected or not.

Just to give you an idea of what is going on visit my code in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6EwHr/8/)

You will see that I get back only data that are selected which is not ideal for what I am trying to do which is submit the form with all the elements of the right select list.

**Note:** The `$('.submitForm').click(function (e))` **MUST** stay the same. I could create a new function to do that and then call the `$('.submitForm').click(function (e))` but this will create an extra step in the process.

So my question really is if I can somehow get all the data from the right select box without having to create a new function just for this form.  and without altering `$('.submitForm').click(function (e))` which is being used by 8 different forms.

**Update**
On a second thought, I don't think I can call the `$('.submitForm').click(function (e))` from a new function so that will create an extra issue

Comment: Please post the relevant code here not just in the fiddle.  When you serialize a form you get the data which would be submitted were a normal submit to be made.  So only the selected checkboxes/radio/buttons etc are included.  Why do you want them all - you don't then know which are selected?  So what's the point?  Or do you want each one with a boolean value?  or what?

Comment: Probably because it's a select multiple box that let's you choose multiple values.

Comment: @Adam Well, when you open the modal you are able to transfer values to each list correct? When you do that, you only have one item selected (the item you moved) so when you press submit you don't have all the items of the list selected therefore only that specific item gets submitted. If you would use the code in jsFiddle you will be able to see the outcome and what I am talking about

Comment: @Mastrianni Yes, but when you submit the form you need to have all the items in the list selected or else you are missing values onSubmit

Comment: Ah!  I see.  I see also that it has been answered. :)

Comment: @Adam well, thanks for the comment anyway sir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an onclick event to your 'Save' button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success submitForm" onclick="listbox_selectall('d', true);">Save</button>
```

This will be called before your jQuery event listener.

Comment: Now that is what I am talking about! :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just a comment:

You can replace all of this:

```
var increment = -1;
if (direction == 'up') increment = -1;
else increment = 1;
if ((selIndex + increment) < 0 || (selIndex + increment) > (listbox.options.length - 1)) {
    return;
}
var selValue = listbox.options[selIndex].value;
var selText = listbox.options[selIndex].text;
listbox.options[selIndex].value = listbox.options[selIndex + increment].value
listbox.options[selIndex].text = listbox.options[selIndex + increment].text
listbox.options[selIndex + increment].value = selValue;
listbox.options[selIndex + increment].text = selText;
listbox.selectedIndex = selIndex + increment;
```

with

```
var newIndex = selIndex + (direction == 'up'? -1 : 2);
if (newIndex > -1 && newIndex < listbox.length + 1) {
  listbox.insertBefore(listbox.options[selIndex], listbox.options[newIndex]);
}
```

and also all of this:

```
var newOption = document.createElement("option");
newOption.value = option.value;
newOption.text = option.text;
newOption.selected = true;
try {
  dest.add(newOption, null);
  src.remove(count, null);
} catch (error) {
  dest.add(newOption);
  src.remove(count);
}
```

with:

```
dest.appendChild(option);
option.selected = true;
```

Also, you shouldn't declare variables inside blocks. There is no block scope in javascript, so better to declare variables at the top of the function (except for loop counters declared in *for* statements).